# $count_posts->draft & published

Tags: count

Currently our portfolio is stacking up a lot and want to show a few projects less instead of showing all. Still, I'd like to show an indication how many projects we did in total. Currently I have the following code and need to count the drafts & published posts.

```
        $count_projects = wp_count_posts( 'apps' );
        $published_projects = $count_projects->publish;
        $total = $published_projects + 11;
```

How can I count all drafts & published posts together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you are getting only the count of published items (**obviously!!!!**):

```
$published_projects = $count_projects->publish;
```

You should do something like this:

```
$count_projects = wp_count_posts( 'apps' );
$published_projects = $count_projects->publish;
$draft_projects = $count_projects->draft;
$total = $published_projects + $draft_projects;
```

More details and examples in [`wp_count_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) reference.